# Conditionally merging two separate JSON objects in JQ

Tags: json, jq

This is how my input looks:

```
{
"text" : "Some text here"
}
{
  "usage": {
    "text_units": 1,
    "text_characters": 101,
    "features": 1
  },
  "language": "en",
  "categories": [
    {
      "score": 0.655041,
      "label": "/technology law, govt and politics/espionage and intelligence/surveillance"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.639809,
      "label": "/technology and computing/computer security/network security"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.624533,
      "label": "/business and industrial/business operations"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using JQ, if the first element of array `category` in the second object contains `/technology`, I want to add a new field named `relevant` with `1` as value (which I managed), and copy the `text` field from the first object.

So, the expected output is:

```
{
  "usage": {
    "text_units": 1,
    "text_characters": 101,
    "features": 1
  },
  "language": "en",
  "categories": [
    {
      "score": 0.655041,
      "label": "/technology law, govt and politics/espionage and intelligence/surveillance"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.639809,
      "label": "/technology and computing/computer security/network security"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.624533,
      "label": "/business and industrial/business operations"
    }
  ],
  "relevant": 1,
  "text": "Some text here"
}
```

And this is what I have done so far:

```
if .categories[0].label  | test("/technology"; "i") then . |=( . + {"relevant": 1} + {"text": .text}) else . |= . + {"relevant": 0} end
```

- [Link to a demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/TomoyRY3y_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input consists of two separate objects. In order to be able to access the first while processing the second, you could save the first into a variable.

```
. as {$text} | input | if .categories[0].label | test("/technology"; "i") then . + {relevant: 1, $text} else . + {relevant: 0} end
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7uXB959Xjh)</sup>